# CVS Checkout into existing directory that does not already contain CVS meta files

Tags: cvs

I have a script that creates a directory, writes some logfiles into it, and optionally tries to checkout some CVS files into it. However, this is failing on a fresh run where the CVS meta folders and files (CVS/Entries etc) do not already exist.

In the snippet below I show that I can delete folder `module` then check out file `module.prj` under module `module`, which re-creates that folder and subfolder CVS with several CVS meta files, and checks out `module.prj`. An immediate re-run of the checkout works because all that stuff already exists.

However, if I delete the CVS subfolder (to simulate the scenario where the folder `module` was created by another script already), the next attempt to checkout `module.prj` fails because those files are missing. Similar behaviour if delete `module.prj` itself.

Is there some additional switch or option I can add to tell CVS to add the requisite meta files if they're not already there?

Thanks.

```
$ rm -vrf module
removed directory 'module'

$ cvs.exe checkout module/module.prj
U module/module.prj

$ cvs.exe checkout module/module.prj

$ rm -vrf module/CVS
removed 'module/CVS/Entries'
removed 'module/CVS/Entries.Static'
removed 'module/CVS/Repository'
removed 'module/CVS/Root'
removed directory 'module/CVS'

$ cvs.exe checkout module/module.prj
cvs.exe checkout: cannot open CVS/Entries for reading: No such file or directory
cvs.exe [checkout aborted]: no repository

$ rm -v ./module/module.prj
removed './module/module.prj'

$ cvs.exe checkout module/module.prj
cvs.exe checkout: in directory module:
cvs.exe checkout: cannot open CVS/Entries for reading: No such file or directory
cvs.exe [checkout aborted]: cannot open CVS/Entries.Static: No such file or directory
```